# Data comparison between records on Filemaker database and website

Tags: database, filemaker, data-comparison

So I have been tasked to create a program that compares the data on our Filemaker database with that of a website that contains the same set of data and identify discrepancies between the two. Any ideas on how I would go about this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much :)

I have been looking at some approaches that potentially utilise some of Filemaker's APIs, SQL queries as well as web scraping but was wondering if anybody had a better and clearer approach.

Comment: Where does your web site get its data from?

Comment: So the website is third-party. We are a company that deals with suppliers where we put in orders with them and some of them have customer portals. Sometimes when we place these orders with them there are discrepancies and I want to create a program that compares the data we have with those on these customer portals automatically identifying discrepancies where currently this is done manually.

Comment: Do you mean you want to compare your data for a particular supplier with the data shown on that particular supplier's website, with each supplier having their own website with potentially very different characteristics??

Comment: That is correct, but for the time being I will focus on our main supplier so we only need to compare our Filemaker data with one website for now.

Comment: I see. I think your question is too wide in general, certainly for SO. There are multiple aspects to this, each deserving a separate discussion: how to get the data from the supplier (web scraping should be your last choice IMHO); how to ingest it into Filemaker (assuming you want to do the comparison inside Filemaker); what constitutes a "discrepancy" - and from this: how to detect such discrepancy and how to present it.